# Scheduling A Weekly Script for rebuild Mysql Index

Tags: mysql, scalability, database-indexes

We are planning to deploy a Stored Procedure to rebuild index. As per below specifictions on Mysql forum. Someone can send any sample script do the same for all table in a particular Database. Will there is any concern or any issues we could face for below script running on weekend.

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html#rebuilding-tables-alter-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a the mysql script to Optimize the Mysql DB. However as said earlier its rarely required since InnoDB is itself able to do the same.

```
USE VIPLamar; 
DROP PROCEDURE IF  EXISTS Lamar_Index_Rebuild_Script;
DELIMITER //

-- call Lamar_Index_Rebuild_Script();
CREATE PROCEDURE Lamar_Index_Rebuild_Script()
mysp:BEGIN

Declare v_max_counter int;
Declare v_counter int;

Declare v_query longtext;
Declare v_table_name varchar(1000);
Declare v_datetime datetime default now();
DROP temporary TABLE if exists temp_todo;

create temporary table temp_todo
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    `table_name` varchar(1000)
);

create table if not exists VIP_Lamar_Index_Rebuild_Script
(
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    `table_name` varchar(1000),
    start_date datetime,
    finish_date datetime
);

insert into temp_todo (table_name)
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();

-- loop thru table
-- check if table exists
Select max(id) Into v_max_counter from temp_todo;
Set v_counter = 1;
WHILE v_counter <= v_max_counter 
Do
    select  `table_name` into  v_table_name from temp_todo where id = v_counter;
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE  table_name = v_table_name AND table_schema = DATABASE()))
    THEN
        set v_query = concat('OPTIMIZE TABLE ' , v_table_name , ';');
        set @stmt = v_query;
        PREPARE tempstatement FROM @stmt;
        EXECUTE tempstatement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE tempstatement;
    END if;

    set v_counter = v_counter +1 ;
end while;   

insert into VIP_Lamar_Index_Rebuild_Script(`table_name`,start_date,finish_date)
select table_name,v_datetime,now() from temp_todo
;
-- select * from VIP_Lamar_Index_Rebuild_Script;
-- drop table VIP_Lamar_Index_Rebuild_Script;

DROP temporary TABLE if exists temp_todo;

END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Index's are kept up to date in InnoDB, statistics can get out of date. Post 5.6 even that is rarely needed to my knowledge. Running the Alter command will repair the table, which will repair any fragmentation. You can read about the different types of algorithms that are available to ALTER TABLE here:
[ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

If however you want to check the database over, you can use the check mysql command which does ALTER as well as a few other bits n pieces to optimise index's, update statistics etc.
[mysqlcheck](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html)

Comment: Hey thanks, We did run the optimize query on Weekend. Do not feel anything improves on Monday. I dont seem to any other tricks with DB performance in my bucket.

Comment: Have you looked at your query plans? What does your cpu usage, memory and disk look like? I’d recommend checking your query plans first though :)

Comment: That's not a universal solution.
On large tables with innodb I have repeatable index degradation, down to 1/10000 of the normal access speed. Especially on indexes that should be HASH type (but innodb only has btree)
Now an "OPTIMIZE" or "ALTER" would naturally solve this but here again you need to have storage AND time. On huge tables it can take a week to complete an OPTIMIZE and you need that TB storage and if there is any tiny corruption inside the table you'll end up with nothing.